# How to refer a variate with correct form in Kdb+?

Tags: sql, database, time-series, kdb

I am using cli of Q. I found there are always 2 ways to refer a variable amid the context, as the belowing codes:

```
q)p:`AAPL`AAPL`GE`IBM`GE`IBM`GE`GOOG`GE`IBM`AAPL
q)x:`u#distinct p / apply the unique attribute
q)e:`x$p
```

At the 3rd line, `x` and `p` both refer to a table variate, but in the call of `$`(enumeration), it is required to use `` `x `` (as a symbol) to refer the related table, while use `p` directly (without back quote) to refer the other.

When shoudl I use the name with a back quote prefixed, and when not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends based on the operations you are performing.

The https://code.kx.com/q website can guide you on when to use `` ` ``

Including documentation on [enumeration](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/enumerations/).

`` ` `` prefixing the variable name can generally be seen to be used when the language wants to reference a global object rather than using it's value.

A good example where the `` ` `` can be used or not to give different meaning to your code is https://code.kx.com/q/ref/update/

```
q)t:([] a:1 2 3)
q)update a+1 from t //Perform an update and return the updated table
a
-
2
3
4
q)t2:update a+1 from t //Perform an update and store the result in t2
q)t2 
a
-
2
3
4
q)t //The global t table remains independent and unchanged
a
-
1
2
3
q)update a+1 from `t //Perform an in-place update to the global t variable
`t
q)t //t has been updated
a
-
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 2):

The exact answer will depend on the operation, since different operators accept different types. Enumeration in particular requires a symbol in its left argument and a symbol list in the right one. The fact that the symbol contains the name of a variable is part of the preconditions of the operator. In fact you could use a variable on the left side (`x$p`) but that would only work if the variable `x` contained a symbol, and then the variable named by that symbol would be the enumeration domain.

Other places where the usage of symbols is significant are table modifying operations (e.g. `update`, `delete` and `xkey`). If you provide the variable name, that counts as an expression and you get the modified table without the original variable being modified. On the other hand if you provide a symbol, it counts as a name and the variable with that name will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

One additional example which is relevant to enumeration:

```
q)s:`a`b`c

/using "?" and referencing the object by value results in a "find" (index lookup)
q)s?`c`d`b`a
2 3 1 0

/using "?" and referencing the object by name results in an enum-extend (enumeration, extending the enumeration list if required). 
q)`s?`c`d`b`a
`s$`c`d`b`a

/"d" was added to the enumeration domain
q)s
`a`b`c`d
```

Ultimately these overloaded operations are what allows kdb to perform many operations on a limited character list. The interpreter recognises the different overloads.